# MySQL Error (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I'm trying to create a MySQL schema for a simple online shop. My existing tables are as follows:

- `user` — user info
- `address` — address info for users
- `product` — product info
- `purchase` — a shopping chart created and purchased by a user

I've created these tables using the following SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    middle_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    registered BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    phone VARCHAR(12),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE product(
    product_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    price DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE address(
    user_id INT,
    address_id INT,
    city VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    district VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    details VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    is_default BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, address_id)
);

CREATE TABLE purchase(
    purchase_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    total_price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    state ENUM('placed', 'paid', 'shipped', 'received', 'completed', 'cancelled') DEFAULT 'placed',
    user_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    full_address VARCHAR(85) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(purchase_id)
);
```

Now I'm trying to create a final table to store individual items in a shopping chart like this:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_item(
    purchase_id INT,
    product_id INT,
    product_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(purchase_id) REFERENCES purchase(purchase_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(purchase_id, product_id)
);
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I don't any errors if I update the foreign key for products as follows:

```
FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

I want the `purchase_item` to be deleted if the corresponding `purchase` gets deleted, but not when the corresponding `product` gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html says:

> If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

But your `purchase_item.product_id` column is part of that table's primary key, which implicitly makes the column NOT NULL.

You cannot use the `SET NULL` action for the primary key on that column.

Comment: Thank you, I just thought it's not a good idea to delete a purchase record from the database when the related product gets deleted. Do you think there's a better way other than ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: Many apps I've seen don't actually delete a product, they just set some column in the product table like `obsolete` or `is_deleted` or some similar attribute. The app doesn't allow subsequent purchases of an obsolete product, but the record must be kept in the database as a reference for historical purchases. Some people call this a "soft deletion."

Comment: Thanks again for this valuable advice!